# The type javax.media.nativewindow.Capabilities cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jogl

I'm trying to get working some project and I'm getting error:

> The type javax.media.nativewindow.Capabilities cannot be resolved. It
>   is indirectly referenced from required .class files

on line with `new GLCanvas(capabilities);`.
Code goes something like this:

```
GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);
GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
```

I'm guessing that I'm missing some library but which one? I have so far added gluegen-rt.jar, jogl-all.jar, jogl.awt.jar, jogl.core.jar and jogl.util.jar (all of them needen for other dependencies). Only part in the whole project that is underlined by red color is new `GLCanvas(capabilities);`. It's weird since I've used this same or similar code in other projects without needing more than gluegen-rt.jar and jogl-all.jar.
Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Please state the version of each dependency. Also, are you using Maven?

Comment: I'm not using maven. I don't know how to find out which version I'm using. I'm assuming all of them are probably newest version or almost newest version. For example I downloaded jogl.awt.jar from: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjoglawtjar.htm but there's no version information.

Comment: UPDATE: jogl-all.jar and glugen-rt.jar are probably version 2.3, others are downloaded from java2s.com and I didn't find the version number there.

Comment: java2s just provides some obsolete crap, use the official JogAmp website to get our JARs.

Answer (score 1):

download [this](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/jogamp-all-platforms.7z) and add the dependencies like explained [here](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE).

You will find all the jars you need in the downloaded 7z under `/jogamp-all-platforms/jogamp-all-platforms/jar/`

If you need help, just let us know

Comment: You can use the JogAmp fat JAR jogamp-far.jar too, it's in this archive: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/jogamp-fat-all.7z